# How to fix the Binding declaration in this XAML?

Tags: wpf, xaml

The Binding for the following works:

```
<TextBox Name="txtBox" 
    Text="{Binding Source={StaticResource odpSettings}, Path=MyProperty, Mode=OneWay}" />
```

But it doesn't work for this:

```
<TextBox Name="txtBox">
    <TextBox.Text>
        <Binding Source="StaticResource odpSettings" Path="MyProperty" Mode="OneWay" />
    </TextBox.Text>
</TextBox>
```

When I run the second one the text box appears empty, and modifying the value doesn't bind whereas it does with the first.

I need the second one to work because I want to include `Binding.ValidationRules`, such that it can appear as follows:

```
<TextBox Name="txtBox">
    <TextBox.Text>
        <Binding Source="odpSettings" Path="MyProperty" Mode="OneWay" 
                    UpdateSourceTrigger="PropertyChanged" NotifyOnValidationError="True">
            <Binding.ValidationRules>
                <src:ValueIsNumeric ValidatesOnTargetUpdated="True" />
            </Binding.ValidationRules>
        </Binding>
    </TextBox.Text>
</TextBox>
```

What do I need to do to fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Place curly brackets around the source:

```
<TextBox Name="txtBox">
    <TextBox.Text>
        <Binding Source="{StaticResource odpSettings}" Path="MyProperty" Mode="OneWay" />
    </TextBox.Text>
</TextBox>
```

Comment: That worked. I thought I had tried that, but I guess not - I must have been doing something dumb instead!! ....  just gotta wait a couple of minutes to mark it correct. Thanks.